# Algorithms for finding all cliques of a given degree in a graph

Tags: graph-algorithms, clique

Consider a graph with $n$ vertices and maximum degree $Δ$. I would like to obtain all $s$ cliques, where $s≤Δ$ and both of them are small compared to $n$.

Bron-Kerbosch algorithm gives all maximal cliques but that's not quite what I need. I want all s cliques (where $s≤Δ$), including not maximal ones.

Are there any efficient algorithms to do this? Even achieving an exponential speed-up would be good?

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, you can just replace
`if P and X are both empty:
  report R as a maximal clique`
by
`if |R|>= s:
           report R as a s-clique`
in [BronKerbosch1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bron%E2%80%93Kerbosch_algorithm) and it should work. And the other (more efficient) variants of the algorithm can probably be adapted too.

Answer (score 1):

This maybe: https://papers-gamma.link/paper/32
With an open source implementation here: https://github.com/maxdan94/kClist